# codeigniter how to popup notification if amount_requested is greater than amount_available on input

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

how to restrict user not enter amount_requested, if amount_request is greater than amount_available and prompt the notification on input let me say for example **amount_available=30**
i have two fields in

```
 **request_tbl**
    **1. amount_requested** 
    **2. amount_available**
```

Comment: At-least show me some of your code

Comment: this is controller, the manager approves the request by entering the quantity_delivered based on quantity_available

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

check [max Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/att_input_max.asp) html5 attribute
You are using codeigniter php framework

So Input will be

```
<input type="number" onkeyup="availablecheck(this)" name="quantity" min="1" max="<?php echo $amount_available?>">
```

where `$amount_available` is the from database

Js

```
function availablecheck(obj){
    var current_request=obj.value;
    var available_quant=obj.getAttribute('max');

    if(current_request>available_quant){
    obj.value="";
    alert('Request Quantity exceeds, Available quantity is '+available_quant);
    }
 }
```

Comment: but whats available_quant you added in js?

Comment: it is `max` attribute of input which has value from database